# intent filter pathPrefix with question mark

Tags: android

I want to set up an intent filter to handle urls like:
http://mysite.com/?action=delete&id=30492

I've tried setting up my `intent-filter` as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysite.com" android:pathPrefix="/?action="/>
</intent-filter>
```

However, this doesn't work, and my app is not recognized as being able to handle the URL. I know that it's because I'm doing something wrong with my `pathPrefix` because when I remove the `pathPrefix` it works.  I also know that it's related to having the question mark in there because if I remove the question mark from the URL and the `pathPrefix`, it works.

Do I need to escape the question mark in some way?  I tried escaping with a slash (`android:pathPrefix="/\?action="`) but that doesn't work either.

How can I get this intent filter to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The query string (`?action=...` in your example) is not part of the path. AFAIK, you cannot filter on query strings.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to create a generic activity that will make the decision on what activity to launch as a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Since Api 19 you can use sspPattern:

```
android:sppPrefix="//mysite.com/?action="
```

Do not forget remove android:host and android:pathPrefix

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@orgazm-pionerki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60509965/622977) android:ssp seems to fix this issue. I lot couple of hours today.
With a link that look like https://mywebsite.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2 I had to set this data in manifest :

```
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="mywebsite.com" />
<data android:sspPattern="/?param1=.*&amp;param2=.*" />
```