# Intent filter browser android:pathPrefix url parameter

Tags: android, url, parameters, android-intent, intentfilter

So I'd like my activity to catch when an intent (browser) calls the link:

```
http://host/info?username=samplename
```

and not when:

```
http://host/info?username=noname
```

Here is my code coming from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>\
   <data android:host="host" android:pathPrefix="/info?username=samplename" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

I have it working for a simple prefix such as android:pathPrefix="/info"
But I have problem with the character ?
I tried using \? but doesn't work
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path

Anybody would have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [intent filter pathPrefix with question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330806/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-question-mark)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \\?

Because '\' is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern), you will need to double-escape: For example, a literal '*' would be written as "\*" and a literal '\' would be written as "\\". This is basically the same as what you would need to write if constructing the string in Java code.