# How do I remove the browser from the activity stack if it launches my Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

We have been working on ways to launch our application from links in Email messages, and we have something that works pretty well. Only URLs with http/https schemes work properly, so we have written a small 'redirector' in our server application that sees we are coming from an Android browser and redirects to a URI with a scheme that our application launches. All of this is working pretty well.

The only bad part is because the browser is launched between clicking the link in the email, and the Application popping up due to the redirect, when the user hits the back button to go back to their email program after using our application, the browser is shown to the user. The browser is left on a blank page, and the user could become confused by this and not know to press the back button again to get back to their email.

When our application is launched from the link the browser will handle the URL and the redirect will cause our application to appear as usual. However, is there a way inside my application to tell Android that my application effectively replaces the browser on the back stack, so that if the back button is pressed, the user goes back to the Email program as if the browser didn't pop up in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the entire browser in the middle by using an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html). You can register a specific schema to listen for and a given url to launch the application. This will launch your application directly and not put a browser in the middle. The YouTube application uses a method similar I'm sure to open the video directly in the YouTube application. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090441/intent-filter-browser-androidpathprefix-url-parameter) is a question that might point you in a good direction for implementing this.

Comment: Thanks. I already have an intent filter in place. The problem is that using a custom 'scheme' (the part before the ://) doesn't work in an email message. Also, since we can connect to multiple servers with our application, we can't use an intent filter that has a server host name in it either. That's how youtube links work, because youtube.com is in the host. If I could make an intent filter with just part of the URL path, that might work for us. But I don't think we can.