# How to exclude URLs with Android Intent Filters?

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, path

I saw some intent filters like this one.

```
<data android:scheme="http" 
      android:host="m.facebook.com" 
      android:pathPattern=".*"/>
```

Facebook app throws URLs like

```
http://m.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2FBsKtRwSyLmM&h=9AQF5nU03&s=1
```

I want to open those urls that contain youtu.be but NOT user (as I want to open videos in the app not user profiles).

Comment: Not directly familiar but can't you modify your pathPattern to be something along the lines of .*youtu.be* ?

Comment: Problem is that links like ...youtu.be%2FBUser&h... should not be opened. Those are links to YouTube profiles, not videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for something similar, and apparently you can only filter the actual path (in this case "l.php") and not the query string (u=http%3A...).

Here is a similar questions:
[intent filter pathPrefix with question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330806/intent-filter-pathprefix-with-question-mark)

And a workaround (works only if you are looking for references to your own page):
[Android Browser Facebook Redirect Does Not Always Trigger Intent for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036793/android-browser-facebook-redirect-does-not-always-trigger-intent-for-url)